# inner SQL query optimalization

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have problem with SQL query, is any way how to speed up this query?
Table word contains  14 000 rows a query took 4.5631 sec on localhost.

```
    SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM((SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM word w
                    WHERE w.lecture_id = l._id AND active = 1))
        FROM lecture l
        WHERE l.book_id = b._id) AS active_word_count,
    (SELECT SUM((SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM word w
                 WHERE w.lecture_id = l._id))
        FROM lecture l
        WHERE book_id = b._id) AS word_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM lecture l
     WHERE l.book_id = b._id) AS lecture_count,
    b._id,
    b.name,
    b.version
FROM book b



CREATE TABLE book (
  _id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  version tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  lang tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;

CREATE TABLE lecture (
  _id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  book_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  lecture_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=155 ;

CREATE TABLE word (
  _id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  question varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  answer varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  active tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  lecture_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Query returns data, witch are available here: http://pastebin.com/80KNsU7Y

Thank you for help.

Comment: It would help if you explained to us what the query returns (instead of us having to figure it out by looking at your query, which quiet frankly is a bit obscure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added some JOINs. So it should be faster now. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eec80/15

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM word w
        JOIN lecture l ON l._id = w.lecture_id
        WHERE l.book_id = b._id
        AND w.active = 1) AS active_word_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM word w
        JOIN lecture l ON  w.lecture_id = l._id
        WHERE l.book_id = b._id) AS word_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM lecture l
        WHERE l.book_id = b._id) AS lecture_count,
    b._id,
    b.name,
    b.version
FROM book b
```

Comment: Query took 0.5781 sec, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I've added a couple of indexes that will speed up the query written this way. They might also help with the original. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdcf8/1

```
Select
  Sum(Case When w.Active = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) As active_word_count,
  Count(w._id) As word_count,
  Count(Distinct l._id) As lecture_count,
  b._id,
  b.name,
  b.version
From
  Book b
    Left Outer Join
  Lecture l
    On l.book_id = b._id
    Left Outer Join
  Word w
    On w.lecture_id = l._id
Group By
   b._id,
   b.name,
   b.version
```

Comment: @Varon Thanks, confused you for the original poster!

Comment: No problem. Your code seems to be very efficient. +1 for it. I cannot figure out more optimization!